# "Save and copy changes to all stack exchange communities" has no effect

Tags: support, profile-page

I'm trying to use my Stack Overflow display name on other Stack Exchanges sites as well. However, clicking "Save and copy changes to all stack exchange communities" in the SO profile edit view does not seem to change my name (or location) on any of them.

I'm running Firefox and have tried it on two different Linux Mint computers, both times with no success.

Comment: While trying this did you make any changes to your SO profile? (Note that the button is "save and copy _changes_...".)

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: Were you by any chance trying to overwrite the current pony avatar? I think that *isn't supported by design*. Jokes aside, have you checked that you aren't blocking any script from the page? Your wouldn't be the first case of a button silently failing to work because a script was blocked.

Comment: I wasn't, and the only thing I'm blocking is ads.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What exactly have you changed and expect to be copied across to all Stack Exchange sites? If you had not changed the saved value on Stack Overflow when clicking the button, the site will believe it hasn't changed and will not copy it to other sites. Note - you can simply change + copy it from *any other site* you have a user on, it doesn't *have* to be from Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've changed name and location and it hasn't copied to e.g. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/57970